# Google Sheets: Inside "COUNTIFS" statement check if value is contained in range

Tags: google-sheets, compare, countif

I want to count the number of customers who have a zip code in our supported zip codes list. In order to do so, I am currently comparing the zipcode attached to a user to zipcodes in our supported addresses tab. This is the best way I could come up with for the time being but it only works with a single cell as an input:

`=COUNTIF('All Customers'!$E$2,"="&INDIRECT("SupportedAddresses!$D"&MATCH('All Customers'!$E$2,SupportedAddresses!$D$2:$D,0)+1))`

The below function is the same as the above, except it's looking at a range instead of a single row. How do I get the below function to work like the one above? The one above returns 1 or 0 correctly while the one below always returns 0.

`=COUNTIF('All Customers'!$E$2:$E,"="&INDIRECT("SupportedAddresses!$D"&MATCH('All Customers'!$E$2:$E,SupportedAddresses!$D$2:$D,0)+1))`

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I found a workaround but would still love to know how to deal with this in the future/why this is the case

Comment: You could check `SUMPRODUCT` for that

Comment: @LioraHaydont you're right! Would you like to explain more and put it as an answer so I can mark you correct?